# Can I install Ubuntu from one partition, onto another, using the boot installer?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 600 gig hard drive that has a 200 gig partition and a 400 gig partition, If I were to extract the ubuntu install data onto the smaller partition, then boot from that partition, Could I install it on the larger partition?

(all the extracting and such would be done in windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

The OP attempted the installation, was successful, and answered this question in a comment.

- They found that the answer is yes--Ubuntu can be installed from one partition on the disk, to which an Ubuntu live environment has been written, to another partition on the same disk.
- They also mentioned that the installation worked and was fast.

(The comment was since deleted, but it included the text, "I figured out you can. And it is very effective and results in a quick installation.")